# What's the point of closing a question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

What's the point of closing a question if people can still answer, vote it up/down, favorite it and add comments?

I dont get it :(

Comment: why so many down votes?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A closed question *cannot* receive new answers. That is the point. The other activities occur because a *closed* question does not mean it is *deleted*. It can be improved, discussed, and voted to re-open. If the question is a real mess and not salvageable, it will eventually be deleted.

Comment: I agree with your principle of closing questions, but don't you think that closing on this site has become discouragement, not incentive?

Comment: @Peter Turner: This site is collaboratively edited. That includes closing as much as editing and voting. Not *everything* adds value to the site by simple virtue that someone wrote it. Closing a post is an interim way of possibly improving it or, having failed that, removing it. It's not a punishment or repudiation of the author; it's to try as best we can to preserve the overall value of the system for the thousands-to-millions who come after. If someone is not comfortable with the idea of their questions and answers being edited by other  users, this may not be the site for them.